# Each Property-Value in a MyObject-list must be unique

Tags: c#, linq, list, unique, equals

Let's say I have the following object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

And in another class I have a list of these objects:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<MyObject> _list;

    public MyClass(List<MyObject> myObjects)
    {
        _list = myObjects;
    }

    public bool AllUniqueValues()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to check if all MyObjects in the list have an unique (non-duplicated) `Value`. When I use the following it works:

```
public bool AllUnique()
{
    return _list.All(x => _list.Count(y => String.Equals(y.Value, x.Value)) == 1);
}
```

But I have the feeling this can be done easier / more elegant. So, my question, is there a better / more elegant approach to check if all MyObjects have a non-duplicated `Value`, and if so, how?

Comment: Just override the `Equals` function.

Comment: @KevinKal Maybe I should have included more, but the object already has an overridden equal method to check equality of other properties. I've only used a simplified example instead. You're right that overriding the `Equals` method would also be a good approach to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this quite elegant:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool AllUnique<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable, 
        Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        var uniques = new HashSet<TResult>();
        return enumerable.All(item => uniques.Add(selector(item)));
    }
}
```

And now your code becomes:

```
 var allUnique = _list.AllUnique(i => i.MyValue);
```

Comment: I agree with you, this is really elegant, and also re-usable for other lists. Thanks!

Comment: @Anton Gogolev Interessting solution. Do you maybe have made some experiences regarding performance with your solution compared to implementing IEquatable and grouping the sequence? It should be same result (uniqueness), shouldn't it?

Comment: @Dom84 Implementing `IEquatable` sounds like an awful lot of work for such a simple task. Performace-wise, I don't think there will be any significant difference between any of the approaches. There's a thing to note, though: my implementation returns `false` as soon as it encounters first duplicate, whereas one with grouping will have to process the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

One of many way to do it:

```
return !_list.GroupBy(c=>c.MyValue).Any(c=>c.Count() > 1);
```

At least it is a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way of solving this is using a *set* data structure. An unordered collection of unique elements. In .NET, you need to use `HashSet<T>`.

You can either override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of `MyObject` to provide what equality means in your case, or implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

If you instantiate `HashSet<T>` and you don't provide an `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation, then it will use your overrides, otherwise it will use the whole implementation. Usually you implement equality comparers if there're more than a meaning of *equality* for the same object.

### I might still need an ordered collection of elements

If you still need to store your objects in order, you can both store the elements in both the `HashSet<T>` and `List<T>` in parallel.  What you get with `HashSet<T>` is a practically `O(1)` access to your items when you need check if an item exists, get one or perform some supported operations in the collection, since it's a hashed collection, it won't need to iterate it entirely to find the element.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, but personally, I'd do the following:

```
public bool AllUnique()
{
    return _list.GroupBy(x => x.MyValue).Count() == _list.Count();
}
```